# warning: non-constant array size in new, unable to verify length of initializer-list

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

I face a problem similar to this one.

```
int j = 6;
int *k = new int[j]{4};
```

The warning is :

```
warning: non-constant array size in new, unable to verify length 
of initializer-list [enabled by default]
```

I face only a warning, no errors and I run with -std=gnu++11

Plus, I want the constructor called for every instance. If I print the array values, all

Comment: I'm not sure this code does what you want.

Comment: The warning looks very sensible. Consider if it had been `int *k = new int[j]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};` instead. The compiler can't know if there will be enough space in the allocated array for all possible values of `j` (or if the programmer gave too many  values, or fell short on the size).

Comment: what are you **trying** to do? The compiler is telling you that `j` is not a constant, so it can't verify that the number of elements in the initializer list is equal to the size of the array.

Comment: What compiler are you using? This actually doesn't generate any errors with gcc 4.7.2, although it also only initializes the 1st element in the array ... the rest are left as zeroed-values.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, that was very helpful, is there a better way to do this: Create an array of objects where I can call anything but the default constructor to initialize the array objects

Comment: @Vigneshwaren: `std::vector<int> v(j, 4);` **why are people so afraid of vectors???**

Comment: @jason I use the same, I just get a warning, Im figuring out a better way to do create an array object by calling anything but a default constructor

Comment: @Jason - that is, only the first value gets initialized with the value `4` and all the rest get zero-initialized. If there were no initializer, the values would be whatever happened to be in memory.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition i wish i could use a vector for my hash table, but unfortunately my assignment is to implement a hash table with separate chaining as buckets and i'm not allowed to use any container in the std:: :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the compiler is telling you.

The dimension is known only at runtime, so you may only use runtime functionality, such as:

```
std::vector<int> v(j, 4);
// `v` contains `j` ints, all initialised to `4`
```

If you have an element type that cannot be default-constructed, you may construct the elements in-place:

```
std::vector<T> v;
v.reserve(j);
for (size_t i = 0; i < j; i++)
   v.emplace_back(ctor-args-here);
```

You could probably also use an initializer list:

```
std::vector<T> v{
   T(ctor-args-here), T(ctor-args-here), T(ctor-args-here),
   T(ctor-args-here), T(ctor-args-here), T(ctor-args-here)
};
```

and the objects will be moved or, at worst, copied.

The point here is that vector elements don't *need* to be default-constructible.

(Unfortunately I'm not aware of a way to do this without the loop or code repetition.)

Comment: That looks elegant, but say it is a class, and I wish to call a parameterized constructor?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, Section 8.5/16 of the C++11 standard pretty much eliminates the possibility of calling a user-defined constructor for uniformly initializing all the elements of an array of class-types.  Here is the relevant text (I've clipped out a couple of listed items that didn't seem pertinent):

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The destination type is
> the type of the object or reference being initialized and the source
> type is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is
> not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is
> not defined.
>
> — If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized)
> braced-init-list, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
>
> — If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.
>
> — Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: That was useful. Works like a charm, to use vectors. Thanks a ton.